Finding START and STOP for groups of treatment
Using tidyverse here. I have a dataframe which has entries (rows) every hour, and the information whether a certain treatment was applied in this hour.
id <- rep(5, 10)
time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
drug <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "D", "A", "A", "C", "B")
df <- df <- tibble(id, time, drug)

I now want to find the START and STOP timepoint for the groups of treatment, the result I imagine to look like this:
    start <- c(1,1,1,4,5,6,7,7,9,10)
    stop <- c(4,4,4,5,6,7,9,9,10, NA)
    df <- tibble(id, time, drug, start, stop)

      id  time drug  start  stop
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     5     1 A         1     4
 2     5     2 A         1     4
 3     5     3 A         1     4
 4     5     4 B         4     5
 5     5     5 A         5     6
 6     5     6 D         6     7
 7     5     7 A         7     9
 8     5     8 A         7     9
 9     5     9 C         9    10
10     5    10 B        10    NA


I can't wrap my head around how to find these groups. I've experimented with lead()and lag() but I failed.

You can use the consecutive_id function to make groups. For example
df %>% 
  group_by(run=consecutive_id(drug)) %>% 
  mutate(start=min(time), stop=max(time)+1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-run)

will return
      id  time drug  start  stop
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     5     1 A         1     4
 2     5     2 A         1     4
 3     5     3 A         1     4
 4     5     4 B         4     5
 5     5     5 A         5     6
 6     5     6 D         6     7
 7     5     7 A         7     9
 8     5     8 A         7     9
 9     5     9 C         9    10
10     5    10 B        10    11

This does assume that all times are consecutive and the data is sorted by time.

Thanks! A first try looks VERY promising. I tried to get the "run" variable myself with lead/lag but failed... "How consecutive" do the times have to be? I mean, the leading row always has a "younger" time, so to say, but the interval might be vastly different. I'll check in the next days with my real dataset. Thanks again

It doesn't actually look at the time (it does assume it's already sorted). It just looks at the drug column and created a new group each time the drug value changes

You could check if the lead drug is different, and if it is, store the lead time as end. Then after grouping by same drug, you can fill so that the end time is propagated throughout the group. This would allow for gaps in time if present.
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  mutate(end = ifelse(drug != lead(drug), lead(time), NA)) |>
  group_by(id, group = consecutive_id(drug)) |>
  mutate(start = first(time)) |>
  fill(end, .direction = "up") |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(id, time, drug, start, end)

Output
      id  time drug  start   end
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     5     1 A         1     4
 2     5     2 A         1     4
 3     5     3 A         1     4
 4     5     4 B         4     5
 5     5     5 A         5     6
 6     5     6 D         6     7
 7     5     7 A         7     9
 8     5     8 A         7     9
 9     5     9 C         9    10
10     5    10 B        10    NA

